# Stack overflow on recursive function

Tags: function, recursion, stack, overflow

got a Problem with recursive funktions. I made this one in java, that is just pretty basic, but doesn't work tho, due to an Stack overflow error. I mean what this function does is to open the funktion just as often as the size of the difference between a given number and the number you declare in the main funktion, what should really not be a problem for the stack, but well, doen't work the whole time, or whats the mistake here...?
thanks for the answers in advance :)

```
public class Übung_Baeume {
    static int anzAufrufe=0;
    static int zahl=23;
    public static int zaehleAufrufe(int uebergabe)
    {
        anzAufrufe++;
        if (uebergabe==zahl){
            return anzAufrufe;
        }


        return zaehleAufrufe(uebergabe-1) + 
            zaehleAufrufe(uebergabe+1);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(zaehleAufrufe(40));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This almost always means that nothing can stop the recursion from going deeper and deeper. There is no condition that stops when a certain level is reached whether the goal is achieved or not.

In your code you start from 40 and will stop only when you get to 23. But one of your branches is increasing the number:

return zaehleAufrufe(uebergabe-1) + **zaehleAufrufe(uebergabe+1)**;

and will never go down to 23.

Welcome to StackOverflow with a stack overflow :)

P.S. The best thing to do is to reconsider your algorythm. If in a case you are *sure* you want to use a recursion, but it's branching is unpredictable due to depending on unknown data, you can put a level-limiting value. It is a *dirty hack* but there are cases when it is useful.

> It is importaint to say that with this limit your code will **still fail**
>   - it will try to call this function as much as 2^33 times = about 8 billion, which is big enough :)

```
public class Übung_Baeume {
    static int anzAufrufe=0;
    static int zahl=23;
    static int max_level = 32;
    static bool fault = 0;
    public static int zaehleAufrufe(int uebergabe, int level)
    {
        if(level == max_level)
        {
            fault = 1;
            return 0;
        }
        anzAufrufe++;
        if (uebergabe==zahl){
            return anzAufrufe;
        }


        return zaehleAufrufe(uebergabe-1, level+1) + 
            zaehleAufrufe(uebergabe+1, level+1);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int ret = zaehleAufrufe(40,0);
        if(fault == 0)
           System.out.println(ret);
        else
           System.out.println("Fault - recursion level limit reached!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ubergabe` if not equal to `23` will recurse with `ubergabe +1` and `unbergabe - 1`. Now each of those will do the same so you can just try this out:

```
zaehleAufrufe(40) ; ==>
zaehleAufrufe(39) + zaehleAufrufe(41) ; ==> neither of these are 23
zaehleAufrufe(38) + zaehleAufrufe(40) + zaehleAufrufe(40) + zaehleAufrufe(42)
```

Notice that last one.. Even though some of these eventually will hit a base case you see that you on the 3. expansion have 2 `zaehleAufrufe(40)`. Each one of these expands like the above turning also into two `zaehleAufrufe(40)` and no one of these will even hit a base case.

For recursion to work you need to become simpler problems and in fact yours become several of the same amount and thus infinite recursion.

To open a function as many times as the difference you only recurse once:

```
public static int zaehleAufrufe(int uebergabe)
{
    anzAufrufe++;
    if (uebergabe <= zahl) {
        return anzAufrufe;
    }
    return zaehleAufrufe(uebergabe-1);
}

zaehleAufrufe(40) ; ==>
zaehleAufrufe(39) ; ==>
...
zaehleAufrufe(23) ; ==> 18
```